# VueJS project not updating when creating new Docker Image

Tags: docker, vue.js, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

**What is it about:**

I currently need to learn how Docker works and therefore I started working on a small project. I have a VueJs Frontend (something pretty basic) and a python API (pretty Basic as well). I managed to create a Docker Volume with 2 containers (1 for the vuejs, 1 for the py API).

**The problem:**

After making the docker containers (both worked) I started working on the VueJs project and nearly finished it now. The problem is, when I try to create a new Image (with that updated vuejs project), and create a new container with that new Image, I always get the default VueJs page when opening the project. It then looks like nothing updated on the vuejs project but it acutally did.

VueJs: **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

#After npm run build successful, publish to nginx:
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

volumes:
  M210-Project-Youtas-v0.2:

services:
  vue-nginx:
    image: vuejs/youtas-v0.2
    volumes: 
      - M210-Project-Youtas-v0.2:/etc/nginx/templates
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    environment: 
      - NGINX_PORT=80

  pythonflask-api:
    image: pythonflaskapi/youtas-v0.2
    volumes:
      - M210-Project-Youtas-v0.2:/etc/flask/templates
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
```

**What I tried**

- I ran this command to make sure vue builds the latest changes to production version:

  npm run build
- I tried deleting the old containers,images and volumes.
- I tired to change the volume name

**UPDATE**

I restarted my computer and now I can see the changes I've made to the vuejs project when connecting to the docker container. But that can not be the only way of doing this.

Comment: Have you updated the `vue-nginx: image: vuejs/youtas-v0.2` according to the NEW image you have created?

Comment: Yes I always updated the 'image' property in the docker-compose.yml when creating new images.

Answer (score 2):

## New solution

If you bild vuejs app to separate docker volume (shared with nginx):

```yaml
  frontend:
    ...
    volumes:
      - vue_dist:/frontend/dist
  nginx:
    ...
    volumes:
      - vue_dist:/dist
      ...
```

and when rebuild is needed you could run

```bash
sudo docker volume ls
# find <actual_volume_name> of vue_dist
sudo docker volume rm <actual_volume_name>
sudo docker compose up --build
```

## Old solution

When I had the same problem (static vue files of `npm run build` were not updated on containers restart and on image rebuild), the remove of docker volume helped:

1. Stop docker containers (with `sudo docker compose down` or `sudo docker stop CONTAINER_ID`).
2. Remove thir images with `sudo docker rmi IMAGE_ID` (`sudo docker images` to show IDs first).
3. Show your volumes with `sudo docker volume ls` and remove volume which contain vue built files with `sudo docker volume rm VOLUME_ID` (and other volumes which contain not valuable files).

You also can use `sudo docker system prune -a --volumes` to remove all volumes (if you don't know where vue build files are).

Tested on Ubuntu 22.

!!! BE CAREFUL, don't occasionally delete volumes with valuable data, SSL certificates etc.